# iOS push notification not received for Distribution mode

Tags: php, ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I am integrating push notification into my iOS app. I am following this tutorial http://www.raywenderlich.com/32960/apple-push-notification-services-in-ios-6-tutorial-part-1 to send push.

I can successfully sent push on `development mode`. When I tried to send push from server on `Distribution mode`, push not received on device.

I have

a) created `aps_develoment.cer` for development purpose and `aps_production.cer`for distribution purpose

b) export `push.p12` from keychain and converted to `pushChatKey.pem`

c) created `pushChatCertDev.pem` from `aps_development.cer` and `pushChatCertDis.pem` from `aps_production.cer`

d) created `combineDev.pem` from `pushChatCertDev.pem` and `pushChatKey.pem`. Similarly created `combineDis.pem` from `pushChatCertDis.pem` and `pushChatKey.pem`.

I followed the above tutorial and successfully sent push in `Development mode` from terminal. PHP script is

```
<?php

$deviceToken ='eff527a7f5f3127d55a63269538498bff2134c6d7b72e4920809d0a102aa04d6';
// Put your private key's passphrase here:
$passphrase = 'Nopass@1234';

// Put your alert message here:
$message = 'TJS push notification test';

$ctx = stream_context_create();
stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'local_cert', 'combineDev.pem');
stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'passphrase', $passphrase);

// Open a connection to the APNS server
$fp = stream_socket_client(
'ssl://gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195', $err,
$errstr, 60, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT|STREAM_CLIENT_PERSISTENT, $ctx);

if (!$fp)
exit("Failed to connect: $err $errstr" . PHP_EOL);

echo 'Connected to APNS' . PHP_EOL;

// Create the payload body
$body['aps'] = array(
'alert' => $message,
'sound' => 'default'
);

// Encode the payload as JSON
$payload = json_encode($body);

// Build the binary notification
$msg = chr(0) . pack('n', 32) . pack('H*', $deviceToken) . pack('n', strlen($payload)) . $payload;

// Send it to the server
$result = fwrite($fp, $msg, strlen($msg));

if (!$result)
  echo 'Message not delivered' . PHP_EOL;
else
  echo 'Message successfully delivered' . PHP_EOL;

// Close the connection to the server
fclose($fp);

?>
```

Push sent into iPhone 4S on development mode. Then I download same app from app store into my iPhone 4S. I uploaded php script into my server and replace `combineDev.pem` with `combineDis.pem`. When I run php script from server it shows

`Connected to APNS Message successfully delivered`

but no push received at iPhone 4S. I also tried with replacing `ssl://gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195` by `ssl://gateway.push.apple.com:2195` but no luck.

Please help. I am stuck here for 8-10 hours.

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure that certificate used for distribution is distribution certificate?

Comment: one more thing.. push are not reliable..means no 100% guarantee that they will be delivered

Answer (score 0):

In your above code change the line

```
stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'local_cert', 'combineDev.pem');
```

to

```
stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'local_cert', 'combineDis.pem');
```

Comment: I did this and mentioned. No luck